# Task.Run in the while loop cause a cpu usage full

Tags: c#, .net, task

code here:

```cs
var localadd = IPAddress.Any;
var server = new TcpListener(localadd, 6300);
server.Start();

while (true)
{
  var client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
  Task.Run(() => ThreadProc(client));
}
// The cpu cost is as normal as usual.
```

The code above could run in expectation,But!
When i move the ***client*** variable out of the while loop,then it will make whole CPU usage nearly full.
code here:

```cs
var localadd = IPAddress.Any;
var server = new TcpListener(localadd, 6300);
server.Start();
var client = server.AcceptTcpClient();

while (true)
{
  Task.Run(() => ThreadProc(client));
}
// The cpu cost nearly 100%!!!
```

Could somebody else explain for this thing?

Comment: So this is working code and if you do some changes it's not working? ... Well, then show not working code

Comment: Well yes, with the latter code you're just creating an infinite number of tasks, with no pauses. It's unsurprising that that causes problems. It's not clear *why* you wanted to move the `AcceptTcpClient` call outside the loop...

Comment: @JonSkeet to share only one TcpClient in many threads.

Comment: I strongly suspect that's not actually a useful thing to do. How are those tasks going to coordinate? Do you really mean to only accept a single TCP connection? And by "many", did you really mean "infinite"? Because that's what you've got at the moment. Starting an infinite number of tasks is not going to end well.

Comment: So Why does it cause a high usage of cpu?Could you figure it out?

Comment: anyway ... every connection needs own client... if any client connects to TcpListener it creates would create new instance of TcpClient

Comment: @KomiShao: Which part of "you're trying to start an infinite number of tasks" do you expect to work *without* high CPU usage? Even without tasks being involved, infinite loops with no delay between iterations are going to cause problems...

Comment: just test `while (true)
{
 Task.Run(() => {});
}` ... it takes 100% because it involves multiple cores (and there is no yeld)... while `while(true) { }` will only work on one

Comment: @Selvin That's true.I just found a really ridiculous situation is that when the client variable announce inside the while loop it just run only once...So,it won't produce too much tasks to use cpu...

Answer (score 2):

```
while (true)
{
  var client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
  Task.Run(() => ThreadProc(client));
}
```

The idea behind this code is most likely to wait for connections to your server, and once a connection have been established, handle the processing for that client on a separate background task. So I would expect this to be working as designed. If you want to somehow parallelize processing for a single client, that should be done in the `ThreadProc` method, but you need to be careful to ensure your program is thread safe, so it is probably only worth while if the processing involves lots of heavy, easily parallelizeable computations.

If you change it to

```
var client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
while (true)
{
  Task.Run(() => ThreadProc(client));
}
```

Now we have changed the behavior so that we wait for the *first* client to connect. Then we start *infinite number of tasks* to do the processing for that client. This is most likely not the desired behavior.

Also note that you should have some way for the caller to ask your server to stop accepting new connections, and possibly also to wait for any currently alive connections to finish processing.

If you do not have some special reason to use raw TCP, I would recommend using a higher level protocol if you just want to make some computers talk to each other, there are many to chose from, http, gRPC, zeroMq, etc. Most will be easier to use that writing your own protocol directly on top of tcp.

Comment: First,Really appreciate your answer.But my question is why does it cost much resources in cpu???

Comment: Because you have infinite loop with starting task ... and starting task doesn't take much time ... so its spawns tasks with the same client infinite times

Comment: @KomiShao because you have an infinite loop starting tasks! processing infinite number of tasks will take infinite amount of CPU time, even if the actual work the tasks do is zero, since just running an empty task still involves some overhead.

Comment: @JonasH,@Selvin Thanks you guys,i will figure it out by my own.